# Disturbed with bad thoughts about allah and islam and aulia allah

Tags: evil-thoughts

I am suffering with lot of evil and bad thoughts about all the things on which i have utmost faith. I was never like this it just started a month ago. i Praise allah and rasool allah with my heart and has got utmost fear and love for them. from few days i am getting wierd thoughts about them which makes me feel very guilty. i immediately seek for forgiveness from allah but iam really not happy with this kind of things happening in my life. i am also getting thoughts about all the aulia allah. my situation is very bad i am feeling very scared to take the name of any aulia allah thinking that some bad thought might come up with it. when i am in namaz i am really getting scared to think of anything and also to make dua. when i am praying dua some thoughts are really overruling my words distracting me badly. I request you please help me and provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: [Here](http://www.dawateislami.net/books/bookslibrary.do#!section:bookDetail_559.ur) is a book regarding evil whisper. It would help you a lot. It is in Urdu, hope you can read this

Comment: the moment such whispering comes, be sure and convinced within you that it is from shaitan and reply in mind that Allah and his Rasool(saas) is sufficient for me and your wispering has no value. Have dua to allah at same time to free you from such wisperings..

Answer (score 2):

First of all i'm neither sufi nor salafi. But as far as i understand we don't know who is a wali of Allah (aulia Allah) this is something that only Allah knows. People for some reason may think that one person is a wali, but that doesn't mean that this person has (if he/she is alive) or had the same value by Allah.

These 3 verses from Surat Yunus (Surah 10) explain the islamic point of view of wilyat Allah clearly

> [62] No doubt! Verily, the Auliya' of Allah [i.e. those who believe in
> the Oneness of Allah and fear Allah much (abstain from all kinds of
> sins and evil deeds which he has forbidden), and love Allah much
> (perform all kinds of good deeds which He has ordained)], no fear
> shall come upon them nor shall they grieve. [63] Those who believed
> (in the Oneness of Allah - Islamic Monotheism), and used to fear Allah
> much (by abstaining from evil deeds and sins and by doing righteous
> deeds). [64] For them are glad tidings, in the life of the present
> world (i.e. through a righteous dream seen by the person himself or
> shown to others), and in the Hereafter. No change can there be in the
> Words of Allah. This is indeed the supreme success.

Some Ulama argue from these verses that any Muslim who has faith and believe in the Oneness of God and fear Allah has parts of what is said wilayat Allah.

Therefore the degree of wilyat Allah is different between the believers Mu'minyn and it is nothing that makes them special because it has to do with the faith and fear of God and only God knows this!
And it begins with the faith in the heart and has to be translated into practice to get the love of Allah.

Now to your Question: As far as i know if one feels bad in his faith he should do tawba (repentance), istighfar (retraction) and read Quran maybe there are some dua' you can do.
For example in al Adab al Mufrad of imam al-Bukhari you find this dua' if someone is afraid of shirk...

> "O Allah, I take refuge in You lest I should commit shirk with You
> knowingly and I seek Your forgiveness for what I do unknowingly."
>
> اللّهُـمَّ إِنّـي أَعـوذُبِكَ أَنْ أُشْـرِكَ بِكَ وَأَنا أَعْـلَمْ،
> وَأَسْتَـغْفِرُكَ لِما لا أَعْـلَم
>
> Allâhumma innî acûdhu bika an ushrika bika wa anâ a'lamu, wa
> astaghfiruka li-mâ lâ a'lam.

And last but not least if you have any confusion about your religion and faith you should ask some A'lim as mentioned in the Hadith

> Jabir said: We set out on a journey. One of our people was hurt by a
> stone, that injured his head. He then had a sexual dream. He asked his
> fellow travelers: Do you find a concession for me to perform tayammum?
> They said: We do not find any concession for you while you can use
> water. He took a bath and died. When we came to the Prophet (ﷺ), the
> incident was reported to him. He said: They killed him, may Allah kill
> them! Could they not ask when they did not know? The cure for
> ignorance is inquiry. It was enough for him to perform tayammum and to
> pour some drops of water or bind a bandage over the wound (the
> narrator Musa was doubtful); then he should have wiped over it and
> washed the rest of his body.
>
> [Sunan abi Dawud]
>
> عَنْ جَابِرٍ، قَالَ خَرَجْنَا فِي سَفَرٍ فَأَصَابَ رَجُلاً مِنَّا
> حَجَرٌ فَشَجَّهُ فِي رَأْسِهِ ثُمَّ احْتَلَمَ فَسَأَلَ أَصْحَابَهُ
> فَقَالَ هَلْ تَجِدُونَ لِي رُخْصَةً فِي التَّيَمُّمِ فَقَالُوا مَا
> نَجِدُ لَكَ رُخْصَةً وَأَنْتَ تَقْدِرُ عَلَى الْمَاءِ فَاغْتَسَلَ
> فَمَاتَ فَلَمَّا قَدِمْنَا عَلَى النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم
> أُخْبِرَ بِذَلِكَ فَقَالَ ‏"‏ قَتَلُوهُ قَتَلَهُمُ اللَّهُ أَلاَّ
> سَأَلُوا إِذْ لَمْ يَعْلَمُوا فَإِنَّمَا شِفَاءُ الْعِيِّ السُّؤَالُ
> إِنَّمَا كَانَ يَكْفِيهِ أَنْ يَتَيَمَّمَ وَيَعْصِرَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ أَوْ ‏"‏
> يَعْصِبَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ شَكَّ مُوسَى ‏"‏ عَلَى جُرْحِهِ خِرْقَةً ثُمَّ
> يَمْسَحَ عَلَيْهَا وَيَغْسِلَ سَائِرَ جَسَدِهِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏